# Odd C++ member function declaration syntax: && qualifier

Tags: c++, boost-thread

From [Boost::Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.futures.reference.shared_future):

```
template <typename R>
class shared_future
{
...
// move support
shared_future(shared_future && other);
shared_future(unique_future<R> && other);
shared_future& operator=(shared_future && other);
shared_future& operator=(unique_future<R> && other);
...
}
```

What on earth are those double-ampersands ? I went over "BS The C++ Langauge 3d edition" and couldn't find any explanation.

Comment: I know you couldn't have found it by searching SO, but still a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/844241/why-are-c0x-rvalue-reference-not-the-default (I'll give you a +1 for effort and clarity though. :P)

Comment: Thank you, hopefully the adjustment to the title will enable someone else to locate the solution.

Comment: The problem is symbols are disregarded when searching, so including "&&" doesn't help.  You'd have to know the name "rvalue reference" to find SO questions about it.

Comment: p.s., if you "google C++ && stackoverlow" this is the first hit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a C++0x addition for rvalue references.

See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/rvalue.html.

Comment: it's a bit odd for a library in boost to start using C++0x before it's released.

Comment: @Hassan: No, it's not.  It's much better to experiment with features before they're standardized (one of the main goals of the standard is to "standardize existing practice"), and such experimentation is a main goal of boost.  The actual boost implementation uses the preprocessor to selectively enable use of rvalue refs.